# How to use Realm object to make POST call in android?

Tags: android, realm

In my project my request and response objects are same and I am storing response into a Realm database.

I am wondering if it is possible to use Realm object to make request as well. Request object have multiple inner objects which extends the Realm Object. I don't want inner object to send realm id to server.

Also, in case of POST request, object should not contain any id.

Anybody can suggest a to achieve this?

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use the same object to fetch the retrofit response and to save it in a database, is not Single Responsability (SOLID principles )and, if the response change, then your response object change but your database object knows that the backend has changed too, why? This has not sense... so if you want a maintainable system, create the objects that you need and the mappers to do the conversions.

Comment: I do agree, but in my case the structure for request and response is same and I also need to provide offline support so my database table needs to be in sync with response. After releasing first version code will be freezed and if response is changed then i can always upgrade my db